# How do I slow down/speed up a sound file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, sampling

I have the following MATLAB code that reads in earthquake data from a file, and plays a sound with the data. **How do I slow down/speed up the sound**?

My guess was to modify the sampling rate of the sound function (by multiplying `fs` by *.333* in the sound function, but the graph of the sound file did not change), but I'm not sure if I did that right.

Here is my code:

```
clear all;
%% Load the earthquake data file
load ECE350_Earthquake_Demo.mat
tearth = 0:dt:(length(d)-1)*dt;
t1 = tearth'; %'
%% Play the sound of the earthquake
sound(d, fs)
figure,plot(t1, d);
xlim([0 20]);
title('Demo');
xlabel('time (s)');
ylabel('Seismograph Sound');
orient landscape
delete 'Demo_plot1.pdf'
print -dpdf 'Demo_plot1'
```

Comment: you can slow down or speed up the sound file by altering the frequency, in other words, changing your fs should do the trick. The shape of your graph should not change, since you have not altered any data, but simply changed the number of samples player per second. Your time-axis should be now longer.

Comment: If you want to change how the file sounds, just change the sample frequency in the `sound` function. If you want to change the sampling rate _of the file_ (which will affect the actual sound samples), use `resample`